# Зациклить прокрутку

Tags: drupal, jcarousel

Добрый день!

Делаю карусель контента при помощи jCarousel, сделал View, выводится карусель. Но после того как отображается последний элемент карусели, карусель останавливается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы карусель была как бы зациклена, то есть после последнего элемента появлялся первый и так далее.

Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.jcarousel').jcarousel({
    wrap: 'circular'
});
```

[Документация](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/configuration.html#wrap)

Comment: я так и делал, но почему-то в модуле Друпала это настройка плохо работает, пришлось руками прописывать в самом коде